# Количество строк во всех файлах.

Tags: php, циклы, файлы

Доброго времени суток. 
Захотелось мне попробовать подсчитать количество строк кода в моем проекте. Ну просто ради интересна. Проект состоит из php страниц и функций.
Подумал сделать просто через

```
function countFileLines($file) {
    return count(file($file));
}
```

но вроде как после этого будет много места в оперативке заниматься. 
Хочу попросить советов. Как это можно реализовать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый экономичный по памяти вариант :-)

```
while( ($ch = fgetc($fh)) !== false ) 
{
    if( $ch == '\n' ) $lines++;
}
```

Ну или:

```
while( ($line = fgets($fh)) !== false ) 
{
    $lines++;
}
```

Comment: $fh - это файл же сам?
А можно еще как-то сделать, чтобы код сам находил файлы на сервере? Не вбивать список названий всех файлов, а он сам прошелся по всему имеющемуся в директории home?

Comment: Можно всё, для этого нужно хотя бы попробовать почитать учебник по PHP.